# UITableView don't resize correctly with iPad Smart Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, keyboard

I use this code for adapt a textView and a tableView sizes when the virtual keyboard on iPad is shown:

```
func keyboardWillShown(_ notification: Notification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.textView_bottomLayoutGuide.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
        self.tableView_bottomLayoutGuide.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
}

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.textView_bottomLayoutGuide.constant = 0
        self.tableView_bottomLayoutGuide.constant = 0
    })
}
```

All work fine with the virtual keyboard. With the Apple's physical iPad Smart Keyboard, the textView adapt fine (it just keep in count the shortcut and predictive strip) but the tableView behaviour is wrong: it short itself as if a virtual keyboard was shown.